# Registry Access hook to protect driver

Tags: windows, api, registry, hook, driver

I'm writing a driver for Windows NT that provides Ring-0 access for userspace application. I want to make a utility with exclusive rights to execute any user's commands that would be protected from any external harmful influence.
Surfing the Internet I found that it is necessary to hook some native kernel functions, such as `NtOpenProcess`, `NtTerminateProcess`, `NtDublicateObject`, etc. I've made a working driver which protects an application but then I realized that it would be better to prevent it also from external attempts of removing the driver or forbidding its loading during OS starting like firewall. I divided the task into two parts: to prevent physical removing of the driver from `\system32\drivers\` and to prevent changing/removing registry key responsible for loading the driver (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`).

The matter is that I do not understand how to hook the access to the registry key from kernel space and even not sure that it is possible: all functions from ntdll that work with registry are in the userspace, unavailable from kernelspace. Also all API hooks that I can set from userspace would be in specific proccess's memory context. So we need to inject Dll into every proccess be it current or new.

Is there a method to hook all NT-calls in one place without injecting Dll into every proccess?

Comment: You do realize that you're basically asking for help writing a rootkit.

Comment: I inattentively read MSDN. There are ZwDeleteKey, ZwEnumerateValueKey and etc. I will try to hook these functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this in wrong way. Registry calls is also nt syscalls and reside in SSDT (as another Zw* syscalls). But hooking SSDT is bad practice. Major drawbacks - it`s don`t working on x64 systems because of PathGuard. Right way is use documented specific filtering mechanisms of OS. For registry calls it is Configuration Manager callbacks. There are some caveats for windows xp version of this callbacks (some facilities are unimplemented or bogus) but xp is dead now =). It`s very simple to use it. You can start (and end =) ) from this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545879(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: 'izlesa', thanks for your answer! As for callbacks, I understood that you mean. But I want to experiment exactly with XP, because I'm not writing a rootkit working everywhere, but a simple utility for my pleasure and using by me only.

Comment: if it`s not production level utility you can use Cm callbacks on XP. Avoid SSDT paths anywhere =)

Comment: As for PathGuard, As I know, it is big problem exactly for device developers, but a real rootkits manage to outwit PathGuard =)
However, certainly It is a good approach to provide kernel security.

Comment: But I do develop driver for mastering my skills at writing low level applications